# Make Current Install a Bootable ISO

Tags: linux, rhel, iso, bootable

How can I convert/transfer/make an existing install of Linux into a bootable ISO?

I currently have an RHEL7 install that I need to make bootable on a DVD.  Thanks.

Comment: "create iso from OS RHEL7" example → https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3536321

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the help.